# transitionViewForCurrentTransition is not set error

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios8, presentmodalviewcontroller

Here is my project:
[image]

It only crashes in iOS8.

I have 5 view controllers:rootViewController,A,B,C and D.Every view controller has a button that present another view controller except D. Evert time presenting a view controller, the Manager singleton object will add the presented view controller into an array. The last view controller D, which has a dismiss button, will use the array to dismiss view controller,and here's the code:

```
    while ([Manager sharedManager].viewCont.count) {
    UIViewController *viewController = [[Manager sharedManager].viewCont lastObject];
    [viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    [self removeViewCon];
}
```

But I meet a crash,which shows:
[image]

I use some manage object because I want to manage the view controllers in some case.
My question is why this crash occurs when in "while" statement? Is it about runloop or iOS8 has some features like UIPresentationController that will not allow this case? And how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I get the same error when I execute the following bit of code in iOS8:   `UIViewController *c = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
    [c.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [appController.navController.visibleViewController presentViewController:c animated:NO completion:^{
        [appController.navController.visibleViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        }];
    }];`

Answer (score 1):

I just hit this also.  It seemes the UIPresentationController crashes if it's presenting view disappears before it is done using it.  One fix is to keep the view controller around a little bit longer.